# Is there a proper documentation for linux kernel functions?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

When I come across a new kernel function, like those in "linux/list.h" and "sys/kmem.h", my only sources of help are books like "Linux Device Drivers" or the "Linux Cross reference" page. But the book only cover the most commonly used functions, sometimes the obsolete version, and the cross reference page only gives the function implementation without talking about what the parameters are. If I were lucky, I could find people asking about the function online, but that is not always the case. Is there a good documentation for kernel functions like a man page for most user space functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. Of course "proper" is a matter of opinion.

The [Linux Kernel's documentation web pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/) seems proper to me.

OTOH, I suspect many people would argue that source code itself is the only real proper documentation.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the best documentation is other source code that use the functions in question.  However, I also find info under /Documentation/* very useful in answering the 'why'.

Comment: Good idea, thanks a lot.